# html css layout not rendering as intended

Tags: html, css

I am creating a responsive webpage.

This is what i am trying to do. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t6g1mqp5/)

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="one">#one</div>
    <div id="two">#two</div>
    <div id="three">#three</div>
    <div id="four">#four</div>
    <div id="five">#five</div>
</div>
```

In desktop view I want `#five` to touch the bottom of `#three`.

When you make the screen size small (mobile view) the divs are arranged correctly in order.

How can I make `#five` touch the bottom of `#three` in desktop view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `float: right` from `#five` and add `overflow: hidden`

```
#five {
  width:200px;
  height:70px; 
  background:#368736;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```css
#container {
  max-width:500px;
  width:100%;
  color: #fff;
}
#one {
  width:300px;
  height:200px; 
  background:#66BCD9;
  float:left;
}
#two {
  width:200px;
  height:50px; 
  background:#A1A6E6;
  float:right;
}
#three {
  width:200px;
  height:50px; 
  background:#E3A1E6;
  float:right;
}
#four {
  width:300px;
  height:100px; 
  background:#ED5894;
  float:left;
}
#five {
  width:200px;
  height:70px; 
  background:#368736;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="one">#one</div>
  <div id="two">#two</div>
  <div id="three">#three</div>
  <div id="four">#four</div>
  <div id="five">#five</div>
</div>
```